# Outputting obj files to obj directory in Makefile

Tags: makefile

Hi I wrote this Makefile by modifying this example: https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/how-to-write-a-makefile

```
program_NAME := bin/myprogram

SRC_DIR := src

#
#srces
#
program_C_SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
program_CXX_SRCS :=  $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)

#
#obj files
#
program_C_OBJS := ${program_C_SRCS:.c=.o}
program_CXX_OBJS := ${program_CXX_SRCS:.cpp=.o}
program_OBJS := $(program_C_OBJS) $(program_CXX_OBJS)

#
# include and library dirs; also libraries
#
program_INCLUDE_DIRS := inc
program_LIBRARY_DIRS :=
program_LIBRARIES :=

# flags
CPPFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(program_LIBRARIES),-l$(library))

#
# targets
#

.PHONY: all clean distclean

all: $(program_NAME)

$(program_NAME): $(program_OBJS)
       $(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME)


clean:
   @- $(RM) $(program_NAME)
   @- $(RM) $(program_OBJS)

distclean: clean
```

It works in the following way. The classes below are compiled into an executable "myprogram" which is output in the `bin` directory. The only issue is the object files are created inside the `src` folder, instead of the `obj` folder. How can I modify this makefile such that `obj` files are created in the `obj` folder? Thank you.

```
 /project
        Makefile

        /src
            Class1.cpp
            Class2.cpp
            main.cpp
        /obj

        /bin
            myProgram
        /inc
            Class1.h
            Class2.h
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, you could use e.g. the [`subst` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions) to replace the source-file directory with the object-file directory:

```
program_OBJS  = $(subst $(SRC_DIR),$(OBJ_DIR),$(program_C_OBJS))
program_OBJS += $(subst $(SRC_DIR),$(OBJ_DIR),$(program_CXX_OBJS))
```

Of course you now need to add a target for object-file creation, as these will not be put in the correct place otherwise:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Hi, Joachim, thanks. I also thought I would have to add separate target for Object files now. It would be nice if you could add brief descriptions of what you achieve where though, although for me it is more or less clear too. ps. How come `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o:` target gets executed, I hadn't specified it anywhere as a dependency before?

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like:

```
OUT_DIR=obj
program_bare_OBJS := $(program_C_OBJS) $(program_CXX_OBJS)
program_OBJS=$(addprefix $(OUT_DIR)/,$(program_bare_OBJS))
```